# Gelleriffic: how to get the imagedata onSlideChange event

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

I've implemented Galleriffic for jQuery, I'm trying to get the id of the image which are going to be displayed, so I have to get it on onSlideChange event. I've been trying a lot of differents jQuery selectors and the galleriffic API but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

Anyone can help me?

The js code is like this:

```
 var c=jQuery("#gallery-thumbs").galleriffic({
            onSlideChange:function(b,c){
                        //c seems to storage the index of the image which are going to be displayed
                        //at this point there is no li.selected?¿?
                my_function(image_id);
                        }});

 function my_function(image_id) {
    //do something
 }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-thumbs" style="display: block;">
   <ul class="thumbs">
     <li class="gallery-thumb  selected">
       <a href="#1" src="path/full.jpg" class="thumb">
         <img src="paths/thumb.jpg" id="this_is_a_id" class="thumb">
       </a>
     </li>
     <li  class="gallery-thumb">
       <a href="#2" src="path/full2.jpg" class="thumb">
         <img src="paths/thumb2.jpg" id="this_is_other_id" class="thumb">
       </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle or post a link to the page in question?

Comment: @Jasper, here you can find a example of what I'm trying to do: http://www.efxto.com/ejemplo/ejemplo.html. The id of the thumbnail img is what I'm trying to get when onSlideChange Galleriffic event is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onSlideChange` function is passed two arguments, one is the index of the previous image, and the other is the index of the next image.

```
onSlideChange:function(prevIndex, nextIndex){

    //start with the `#ims-thumbs` div,
    //then get it's only child, the UL,
    //then find all the images in the UL
    //then select the image we want by index and get it's ID
    var image_id = $('#ims-thumbs').children().find('img').eq(nextIndex)[0].id;
    my_function(image_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I tried something similar before but with incorrect syntax. Thanks againg.